# Plotting Mean High Water Mark from DEM LiDAR around mangrove vegetation

Tags: qgis, dem, lidar, contour

I am currently trying to plot a Mean High Water Mark (MHWM) using a 1m DEM created from LiDAR. I have been able to plot a contour value representing MWHM based on tide gauge data. When I create the MWHM contour, the output is providing thousands of 'islands,' with the continuous line much further inland; with some cases not even producing a continuous line. This area along the coast has a lot of mangrove vegetation (up to 400m widths). One thought is that the density of the mangroves has resulted in the LiDAR not penetrated all the way through, hence resulting in this output of many small 'island' contours.

Are there any suggestions/methods/considerations I should be taking into account to best plot MWHM. Note, I wish to maintain accuracy as much as possible, however visual analysis seems to suggestion MWHM would be around where vegetation colouration changes.
[image: yellow line is continuous contour]
[image: Imagery of subject area].

Comment: what software are you using to create the contour? Do you create a DEM first then generate contours from the DEM? Is your LiDAR classified? If so what level? If you have water classified points you should be able to omit them which would reduce the islands.

Comment: I have had success generating cleaner, more accurate topo lines from high-res LiDAR DEMs and photogrammetry DSMs by downsampling the cell size to a coarser resolution. That filters out some of the noise from small, erroneous topographic features. As you say, it's a balancing act where you don't want to downsample too much and sacrifice accuracy. I suspect you're right that the "islands" in your data are misclassified points that are really vegetation.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks for your reply. I am using QGIS. The DEM was created by contractors from the LiDAR they collected (I have reached out to ask for information on their parameters/method). The LiDAR is classified into 9 levels. We have produced a DEM with ground points only from the supplied cleaned LiDAR data and less island contours were produced. However, there were still many. The placement of the contours is also inconsistent with other data that reflects the intertidal zone, so I suspect that the LiDAR / DEM has not been processed correctly... I will continue to investigate.

Comment: @lambertj Thanks for your thoughts. Its good to know that you have experienced similar issues with high-res LiDAR DEMS. I have tried down sampling the cell size and it does result in better looking contours, however still not fantastic.

Comment: Upon further investigation, consultation and above advice, it appears that there is too much noise produced by LiDAR in mangrove areas, and as such is not possible to plot a nice contour - much to my statistical data's dislike.